# In Spring MVC, can't bind an input to a date field with a Jackson @JsonFormat

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jackson

I have an application using Spring MVC that interacts with a REST service. The UI has a typical form input using JSP.

There is an object that I wish to allow the user to modify and persist that includes a date field:

```
public class TheObject {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "PST")
    private Date myDate;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And on the UI this is bound to an input:

```
<form:input path="myDate"/>
```

So, in my controller when I post the form and I've entered a proper "yyyy-MM-dd" string in that input box I get null for the field and a binding error. Controller method looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "thePath", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postMyForm( @Valid @ModelAttribute final theObject backingModel, final BindingResult result, final Model model,
        final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        //Breakpoint here to check the binding
}
```

If I look at the BindingResult there I see an error saying the following:

```
Field error in object 'backingModel' on field 'theDate': rejected value [2016-07-07]; codes [typeMismatch.backingModel.theDate,typeMismatch.theDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [backingModel.theDate,theDate]; 
arguments []; default message [theDate]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'theDate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.util.Date] for value '2016-07-07'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

If I take out the @Valid I get an exception with the same message.

How should I be able to bind this?

If I replace the annotation with @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") then binding works fine. But the object needs that Jackson annotation.

Answer (score 5):

So after posting all that I realized I can just add both annotations and it works

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", timezone = "PST")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date myDate;
```

So I'll post this as the answer in case anyone else comes across this (unless someone thinks what I'm describing above is really bad practice or anything).

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat` will be used for model attribute binding. `@JsonFormat` is irrelevant for that process. `@JsonFormat` will be used for Jackson serialization. `@DateTimeFormat` is irrelevant for that process.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I'd concluded, didn't realize the 2 attributes could go together.